# Change color while hovering over page links in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I need some help with this. I'm trying to change the color when hovering over pages in the navbar. This is in bootstrap.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">page 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the css, I can't figure it out for the life of me. I'm new to bootsrap.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse li a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse li a:focus{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Does `.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse li a:hover` not work?

Comment: works for me : https://jsfiddle.net/yhkb3605/